# Issue in server side validation of file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using server side validation like

```
protected void cvFile_ServerValidateFile(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string[] validFileTypes = { "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "doc", "xls" };
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fiFile.PostedFile.FileName);
    bool isValidFile = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < validFileTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ext == "." + validFileTypes[i])
        {
            isValidFile = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isValidFile)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that the page is still refreshed and files is saved. I would like the page to not be refreshed.

Comment: Page **is** refreshed because of server roundtrip to validate (unless you're using AJAX). To avoid file to be saved you have to check `Page.IsValid` property (it's `false` if validation fails).

Comment: Can you please explain me hiow???

Comment: I am using update panel